# Java and SAP JCoFunction getting no data

Tags: java, saprfc, jco

Hi I need help with a SAP integration with java. I don't know much about SAP but if I'm getting a function with the next template using the Java JcoFunction.

- Input:

  - IV_SIZE_EXCHG
  - IV_TRGID
- Changing:

  - null
- Output:

  - EV_TOTAL_ZDT1
- Tables:

  - ET_ARTICLES
  - ET_LOCATION_KEYS
  - ET_TREAGERS
  - IT_LOCATION_KEYS
  - RETURN
- Exceptions:

My client gets data with SAP filtering by the table `IT_LOCATION_KEYS`. But  as you can see the table is on the output side and not on the input.

Can this work on Java?

By the way there is any way to get all data with a limit or top like in SQL. Thanks.

This is my code:

```
JCoParameterList importParameterList = function.getImportParameterList();

JCoTable articlesTable = importParameterList.getTable("IT_LOCATION_KEYS");
articlesTable.appendRow();
articlesTable.setValue(PARAM_CUSTOMER_NUMBER, request.getCustomer().getCustomerNumber());
articlesTable.setValue(PARAM_CONTRACT_NUMBER, request.getContractNumber());
articlesTable.setValue(PARAM_LOCATION, request.getLocation());
```

And when I tried to get the table IT_LOCATION_KEYS it says that there is no input table.

I also tried to get the table using the next code.

```
JCoTable articlesTable = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("IT_LOCATION_KEYS");
```

This seems to work fine but now the problem is that I still can't get any data by the export.

```
function.getExportParameterList()
```

The result is

```
|------------|
| PARAMETERS 'OUTPUT'
|------------|
|EV_TOTAL_ZDT|
|------------|
|   0   1   2|
|------------|
|00000000000C|
|------------|
```

And the output tables are always empty.

```
function.getTableParameterList().getTable("ET_LOCATION_KEYS");
```

Answer (score 1):

`TABLES` parameters are always changing parameters (in- and output), regardless of their name. It's up to the implementation what they are actually used for.

You will need to use [`getTableParameterList()`](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/javadoc/com/sap/conn/jco/JCoFunction.html#getTableParameterList()) to access the parameter.

Comment: The problem is that when I do on Java the next code   function.getImportParameterList().getTable("IT_LOCATION_KEYS") it says that there is no input table with that name so I can't set any filter to retrieve data.

Comment: ...and rightly so, because it's not an `IMPORTING` parameter but a `TABLES` parameter.

Comment: Ok vwegert and thanks for your answer, can you check the new comments and help me with the data problem.

Comment: No, not without you posting the ABAP code of the function module.

Comment: That is not the code, that is merely the interface definition.

Comment: There you have it